# kohana log files permissions: not writable for group

Tags: logging, filesystems, file-permissions

We're developing an API in Kohana and we've got a problem that our log files have no write permissions for the group. This is how November directory looks like:

```
.../application/logs/2013/11$ ls -al
total 2520
drwxr-sr-x 2 xyz wwwxyz    4096 Nov 26 09:12 .
drwxr-sr-x 9 xyz wwwxyz    4096 Nov 14 09:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz    5769 Nov 14 09:55 04.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz 2511368 Nov 14 09:55 05.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz     876 Nov 14 09:55 06.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz     876 Nov 14 09:55 12.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz     300 Nov 14 09:55 13.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz    1961 Nov 26 08:45 14.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz    1961 Nov 26 08:45 22.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xyz wwwxyz   21165 Nov 26 09:25 26.php
```

`wwwxyz` is the apache user. The today log file (26 Nov 2013) has been manually modified to enable the application to run.

This is how we use log files manually in our application:

> Log::instance()->add(Log::INFO, $content);

this is an access log (it stores all API command logs)

> Log::instance()->add(Log::ERROR, $e->getFile().':'.$e->getLine().' '.$e->getMessage());

and this is an error log (inside try/catch statement).

Currently we need to manually set writable permissions for the group (g+w) for newly created log files. As this solution is unacceptable in the long run, we'd like to find the cause of such situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally found the solution. Kohana's default log file writer looks like this:

```
public function write(array $messages)
{
    // Set the yearly directory name
    $directory = $this->_directory.date('Y');

    if ( ! is_dir($directory))
    {
        // Create the yearly directory
        mkdir($directory, 02777);

        // Set permissions (must be manually set to fix umask issues)
        chmod($directory, 02777);
    }

    // Add the month to the directory
    $directory .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.date('m');

    if ( ! is_dir($directory))
    {
        // Create the monthly directory
        mkdir($directory, 02777);

        // Set permissions (must be manually set to fix umask issues)
        chmod($directory, 02777);
    }

    // Set the name of the log file
    $filename = $directory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.date('d').EXT;

    if ( ! file_exists($filename))
    {
        // Create the log file
        file_put_contents($filename, Kohana::FILE_SECURITY.' ?>'.PHP_EOL);

        // Allow anyone to write to log files
        chmod($filename, 0666);
    }

    foreach ($messages as $message)
    {
        // Write each message into the log file
        // Format: time --- level: body
        file_put_contents($filename, PHP_EOL.$message['time'].' --- '.$this->_log_levels[$message['level']].': '.$message['body'], FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

it works perfectly if your `logs` dir is empty - creates year dir then month dir and finally the day log file (all with proper permissions, overriding umask settings). Our problem was due to deployment - we used rsync over jenkins. We had `-rl` flags instead od `-rlp` (preserve permissions). During jenkins tests, we were running cURL tests that indirectly created log files. Without `-p` flag log files were copied using umask, which applied `g-w`, hence the apache user did not have the rights to write log files.